# Visual Testing Using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have validated buttons and links on web pages but I didn't do the visual testing in GUI Level.
How can I achieve this one using selenium with java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking if particular element meets the expected style. To query a style property you will have to execute JavaScript code with `JavascriptExecutor`

```
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com");
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='LEARN HTML']"));
String contents = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
        .executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).getPropertyValue('background-color');", el);
System.out.println(contents);
driver.close();
```

Having the value of a particular CSS property you will be able to assert if it corresponds to what a user is expected to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with connecting a third party tool, then I would recommend you to have a look at [Galen](http://galenframework.com/). This is an Open Source and can be easily bundled with Selenium and Java to perform any GUI level visual validations. It has a separate report as well to show its GUI level validations

How it works?

1. This tool uses Spec files, which can be written as  below

> ```
> @objects
>   <element> xpath  <xpath>
>
> =Main Section=
>   @on desktop
>       <element>:
>           css color is "rgba(212, 40, 28, 1)"
> ```

2. Java Test will be written to call the spec file